# Is it possible to get results from a site without having access to it?

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to solve a problem where many documents are stored in different sharepoint sites (that aren't necessarily on the same server , meaning they aren't sub sites of the same site).

I'm considering of creating some kind of a custom sharepoint search but my question is this - is it possible for users that don't have access to a specific sharepoint site get search results from that site?

Meaning that if they search for "Document X" and that document is on a site they don't have permissions to i would like them to see on the search result page that that document is located there but still don't let them access it without getting permission (just see that it exists).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to impersonate a specific user and return the search result that user sees to all users. Needless to say that this is of course a security risk, so use with caution:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Principal;

using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace SharePointSearchImpersonation.WebPart1
{ 
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class QuerySearchImpersonatedWebPart : WebPart
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            try
            {
                // Run elevated since the user, the apppool account, that impersonate other users needs the following 
                // local policies (run secpol.msc): "Impersonate a client after authentication" & "Act as part of the operating system"
                // The apppool account must be granted above rights. 
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                    delegate
                        {
                            // Setup the windows identity to impersonate the search as. 
                            WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity("user3@dev.local");
                            // Create a new ImpersonationContext for the identity
                            using (WindowsImpersonationContext wic = identity.Impersonate())
                            {
                                SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();
                                // Get the search proxy by service application name
                                SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("Search Service Application");
                                KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(searchProxy);
                                query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
                                query.QueryText = "test";
                                query.RowLimit = 25;
                                ResultTableCollection result = query.Execute();
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                dt.Load(result[ResultType.RelevantResults]);

                                GridView gv = new GridView();
                                Controls.Add(gv);
                                gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                                gv.DataSource = dt;
                                gv.DataBind();

                            }
                        });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() {Text = ex.ToString()});
            }
        }
    }
}
```